# Can 2 seperate test access the page factory at once?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

I recently switched to the pagefactory model and i noticed when running test in parallel will fail all of the time(It used to work fine before switching over to the page factory model). i have code sample if anyone want to look at it.  I am using Selenium webdriver with testng right now. The first test returns the following

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Build info: version: '2.43.0', revision: '597b76b', time: '2014-09-09 20:52:38'
```

the rest of the test return the following

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
```

also when i run the tests one by one they run normal.

Comment: "SessionNotFoundException" sounds like you are mixing more into your PageObjects than just page objects. You need to post some code. However, I am worried that you are going to post everything under the sun. Have a read through this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have 2 page files. in both i only have methods like the following  
    @FindBy(id="EmailConfiguration")
 public WebElement EmailConfiguration;

Comment: It looks like it has nothing to do with PageFactory - probably you are calling quit() on your WebDriver. Something like - create driver, run tests, quit. Then before running next "parallel" test you do not create new driver

Comment: in the @afterclass im just doing driver.quit(); and init the next driver. Example:                                             driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),
    cap);